# What does label1=label[0,:,:,0] do? Whats the relation of this line with blue and yellow color?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

```
data_aug_iter = temp_ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = data_aug_iter.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    batch_of_imgs, label = sess.run(next_element)
```

The `label1` value is

```
[[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
...
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]]
```

When I want to print  particular processed image, why does it print an image with blue and yellow colors?
I tried mismatching each and every element but it takes only [0,:,:,0]

Comment: Please show how you print your image. Are you using pyplot? It’s default color map has blue and yellow as the min and max colors, if you image only has two shades of gray, it appears blue and yellow.

Comment: Yes, i am printing the image using pyplot. So what do i do to show all the colors of that image?